# Is this Kufr or not?

Tags: halal-haram

If a person utters the name Jesus does that make him a Kufr because christans and Catholics say it so if a Muslim were to say it you would be acting like a Christian or a catholic therefore makes you Kufr?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you've written the question as one long sentence without commas. It seems you know English well enough to do so properly. Are you trying to say that you're not a muslim? In that case, do so directly.

It's not *kufr* unless one believes the simplistic theology held by many Christians as 'Christ is a son of God' as God has no partner. Jesus happens to be a prophet in Islam so to mention 'Jesus' per se is not *kufr* and can be Islamic:

> Jesus declared, “I am truly a servant of Allah. He has destined me to be given the Scripture and to be a prophet." [Q.19:30]

(Please note that quoting does not mean that I am thing quoted. I only say this since I've noticed others take it so. This should really go without saying).

And also:

> And We did certainly give Moses the Torah and followed up after him with messengers. And We gave Jesus, the son of Mary, clear proofs and supported him with the Pure Spirit. But is it [not] that every time a messenger came to you, [O Children of Israel], with what your souls did not desire, you were arrogant? And a party [of messengers] you denied and another party you killed. [Sahih International - 2:87]

(Please note that quoting does not mean that I am thing quoted. I only say this since I've noticed others take it so. This should really go without saying).

Answer (score 0):

‘kufr’ refers to the denial of anything Allah obliges belief in, whatever the Prophet (saw) brought from Allah proven definite and certain; having belief in that with one’s heart that it’s the truth is necessary for one to be a Muslim (believer). Therefore, a person who does not consider any of the definite teachings of the Prophet (saw) to be true or does not approve of them is called a ‘kafir’ (disbeliever). So if one says Jesus just as a name is not a Kaafir. The one who utters it with belief is... Read the following article to understanding what 'kufr' is in Islam. This will provide a clear view on how to determine kufr https://www.islamiqate.com/3998/what-is-the-concept-of-kufr-in-quran.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely not kufr to say the word 'Jesus', because we as Muslims say Jesus or Esa as Allah's messenger, not his son.!

To be a Muslim it is a must to believe in Hazrat Esa (AS) as well. But if you think or believe that he is Allah's son then that indeed is Sirk and Kufr.

To make it more simple, let's just say in Arabic we say 'Allah', in Urdu we say 'Khuda" and in English, we say 'God'. Similarly, we call Hazrat Esa (AS) and they call him Jesus.  No matter what we call him is fine until we start believing the same as what Christians do.

Answer (score -1):

Kufur is to deny and reject an idea related to faith.
Saying the name of Jesus as a matter of speech might go under unintentional saying.
The issue is when a person saying it as a way of asking for help or guidance this goes under shirk(polytheism).

Comment: Jesus is a messenger of Allah recognised in the Qur'an. It is no way shirk to mention his name. It's only shirk to say that he is God like some Christians do.